# I pointed the nameserver to my server ip adreess, configured NSD3 as DNS Server but the domain would not resolve. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: dns, bind, zone, nameservers

I am trying to set up my own nameserver on hp cloud VPS for the domain "appwared.com".

I added ns1.appwared.com from my registrar control panel to point to my server's public ip address.

I installed NSD3 as my DNS software and configured the zone files. It is up and running but as you may see, the domain is not resolving.

here you can see the zone file: http://pastebin.com/z0094kja

This is my first attempt to set up my own Name Server, maybe you can peoint out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: It works for me. If if still doesn't work for you, it could be a caching (aka propagation) issue. try `dig +trace appwared.com`

Comment: I've solved the problem. Apparently, HP was blocking the UDP 53 port that used in DNS.

Comment: Answer your own question and mark it as the answer imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP was blocking the UDP 53 port that used in DNS.